# Convert byte to sequence of bits (binary) in Perl

Tags: perl, byte, bit

I've been banging my head around this question for the past few hours; there's a lot of similar questions around here, but nothing quite the same, and none of the techniques I've seen seem to be working.

I have a sequence of bytes (integers) that I've generated from input in my program - each one represent a red, green or blue color value of a pixel in a BMP image. I essentially need to extract the bitstream representation of each byte; that is, the binary sequence of that byte.

I've been using lots of different variations of `pack()` and `unpack()`, but I'm not coming out with proper results.

For instance:

```
sub convertToBinary {
    my $str = unpack("B32", pack("N", shift));
    return $str;
}
```

I've also tried:

`my $str = unpack("b8", shift);`,

`my $str = unpack("B8", shift);`,

`my $str = unpack("b*", shift);`

And numerous other variations; none of them are seem to be working. I don't feel like it should be too hard to extract the bitpattern of a byte though.. just eight '1's or '0's, right?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you give specific examples of possible inputs and the desired output?

Comment: Sure - that would help. The goal is to find characters encoded in the .BMP - an exercise in stenography. Each pixel in the .BMP has a red, green, and blue value, each of which is represented in a byte of code. Within each byte, the least significant bit will be set to zero, then encoded with a new value as part of the message. I mostly have what I need, but I'm having a hard time extracting the bitwise value of each byte.

Comment: You don't want the bit representation. You can use bitwise `&` to check if a bit is set. That said, you're still incredibly vague about your input

Comment: Right I'll try to be concrete then. My input is a .BMP file. The whole file. I read it in, and use `$offset = unpack("L", substr($bmp, 10, 4));` to find where the actual pixel data begins. So it's a string to begin with. Then, within a `for` loop, I use `$byte = unpack("CCC",substr($bmp, $offset + $counter, 1));` to pull  out each byte - so I end up with a three-character (or 3 digit, I'm not sure exactly) value that represents the amount of red, green, or blue of a certain pixel. I'm trying the byte that contains that value into a sequence of bits, so I can look for the hidden characters

Comment: Although it's quite possible that somewhere prior to that step I did something that caused me to loose the message bit encoded into each byte

Comment: You should probably post a separate question about your larger task of extracting a hidden message from a .BMP.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html)

```
sub convertToBinary {
  return sprintf '%08b', shift;
}
```

Comment: That worked - thank you! At least, it allowed my to get a correct binary representation. I'm still kinda stuck though - I wrote about it more specifically above. I have the binary representation now, but I'm not sure if I've exponentially lost unused bits (which would have housed the message), or if I'm still extracting it incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

Base on a comment, you actually want to check if the least significant bit of a byteis set.

The solution depends what you mean by byte.

If you have an 8-bit character:

```
if (ord("\xAC") & 0x01)
```

If you have an 8-bit number:

```
if (0xAC & 0x01)
```

---

Original answer:

It sounds like you want the binary representation of a byte. The solution depends what you mean by byte.

If you have an 8-bit character:

```
unpack('B8', "\xAC")

sprintf('%08b', ord("\xAC"))

sprintf('%08b', unpack('C', "\xAC"))
```

If you have an 8-bit number:

```
sprintf('%08b', 0xAC)

unpack('B8', chr(0xAC))

unpack('B8', pack('C', 0xAC))
```

All of the above produce the string `10101100`.

Comment: If I have it wrong, could you please specify the inputs and outputs more precisely.

Comment: The `sprintf` method works for returning a binary representation! Thanks.

Comment: I'm still having some difficulty however; I wrote more about it in a comment above. One bit of confusion: when I do `print unpack('B8', 10);`, it produces 00110001. When I plug this into a converter back to decimal, I get 49 - not sure what's going on there

Comment: @Nik, That's not one of the three solution I presented for 8-bit numbers. You're using one of the solutions that expects an 8-bit char.

Comment: @Nik, What's happening is that you're passing the two bytes/chars "10" ("\x31\x30"). Perl proceeds to give the bit representation of the first 8 ("00110001")

Comment: Anyway, I updated my answer to show how to check a bit. BAsed on this information, you want the second (`if (10 & 0x01)`)